# Converting schema-less csv into a C# structure

Tags: c#, .net

I'm receiving data that is in a csv-like format, of varying value types (int, double, DateTime, string, and so on), and is schema-less (the number of columns and the value types are unknown until run time).

I want to parse this data into .NET value types and store it in some kind of structure at run time. What's the best structure to hold this data?

*I'm currently storing it in a DataTable, but it's still a hassle to retrieve strongly typed values out of it. I wanted to see if there were any better ideas I might not have considered.*

Comment: So there is no set list of properties? Both the property names, and their data types are always unknown/random?

Comment: Right, both the column names and data types are only known at run time.

Comment: The structure all depends on what's in the file. You can easily build a class  that can strongly type all of the data points in your CSV

Comment: Cam, see my comment above. The value types are only known at run time, so building a class with a specific set of properties would not work.

Comment: You're about to face a trade-off that's likely not worth it - heuristics and complicated parsing. Stick to datatable or use ExpandoObject - all the same - but don't go down the perfect parsing rabbit hole.  ` ` if you really need strong types and have a predefined types of incoming data then pre-define matching classes and redirect your parsing to each of them

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a class which can hold the property name, and a set of strongly types values:

```
class Container{        
   public string PropertyName { get; set;}
   public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set;}
   public int IntValue { get; set;}
   public string StringValue { get; set;}
   etc.
}
```

Perform checks on the incoming values and place them in the correct property.

```
 string propertyName = array[0];
 string propertyValue = array[1];

 Container container = new Container();
 container.PropertyName = propertyName;

 if (int.TryParse(propertyValue, out intVariable))
 {
     container.IntValue = intVariable;
 }
 else if (... ... ...) {}
 else 
 {
     container.StringValue = propertyValue;
 }
```

Build a list of this object type. You can then sort the list by which property is used, or group the objects as needed.